# LSTM/RNN in pytorch The relation between forward method and training model

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm still fairly new to neural networks, so sorry on beforehand for any ambiguities to the following.

In a "standard" LSTM implementation for language task, we have the following (sorry for the very rough sketches):

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(*args):
    ...

    def forward(self, input, states):
         
        lstn_in = self.model['embed'](input)
        lstm_out, hidden = self.model['lstm'](lstm_in,states)

        return lstm_out, hidden
```

Later on, we call upon this model in the training step:

```
def train(*args):
      
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        ....
        *init_zero_states
        ...
        out, states = model(input, states)
        ...
    return model
```

Let's just say, that I have 3 sentences as input:

```
sents = [[The, sun, is, shiny],
 [The, beach, was, very, windy],
 [Computer, broke, down, today]]
```

```
model = train(LSTM, sents)
```

All words in all sentences gets converted to embeddings and loaded into the model.

Now the question:

1. Does the self.model['lstm'] iterate though all words from all articles and makes one output after every word? or every sentence?
2. How does the model make distinction between the 3 sentences, such as after getting "The", "sun", "is", "shiny", does something (such as the states) in the 'lstm' reset and begin anew?
3. The "out" in the train step after `out, states = model(input, states)` is the output after running all 3 sentences and hence the combined "information" from all 3 sentences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using LSTMs in Pytorch you usually use the `nn.LSTM` function. Here is a quick example and then an explanation what happens inside:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        
        self.embedder = nn.Embedding(voab_size, embed_size)

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedder(x)
        
        # every time you pass a new sentence into the model you need to create
        # a new hidden-state (the LSTM requires, unlike RNNs, two hidden-states in a tuple)

        hidden = (torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size), torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size))
        x, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        
        # x contains the output states of every timestep, 
        # for classifiction we mostly just want the last one
        x = x[:, -1]

        x = self.fc(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x
```

So, when taking a look at the `nn.LSTM` function, you see all N embedded words are passed into it at once and you get as output all N outputs (one from every timestep). That means inside of the lstm function, it iterates over all words in the sentence embeddings. We just dont see that in the code. It also returns the hiddenstate of every timestep but you dont have to use that further. In most cases you can just ignore that.

As pseudo code:

```py
def lstm(x):
    hiddenstates = init_with_zeros()
    outputs, hiddenstates = [], []
    for e in x:
        output, hiddenstate = neuralnet(e, hiddenstate)
    
        outputs.append(output)
        hiddenstates.append(hiddenstate)

    return outputs, hiddenstates

sentence = ["the", "sun", "is", "shiny"]
sentence = embedding(sentence)

outputs, hiddenstates = lstm(sentence)
```

Comment: If a new zeroed hidden states are created before the passing of a new sentence, does it then mean, that the hidden state pair (hidden, cell) in the output only contain information about the current sentence? Does LSTM not learn between sentences, or are those "learned" information saved by updating the weights of LSTM?

Comment: the lstm learns between all the sequence-elements in a sequence. When you sequence is a sentence, the sequence-elements are words. So the hiddenstates are passed from one word to the next in just that sentence. But it depends on your problem. Your sequence could also be a text where every sequence-element is a sentence. But your sequence can also be a word where every sequence-element is a letter. A sequence-elemet is always what you embed. Thats up to whatever your problem is you are trying to solve.

Comment: Great. In a task to classify sentences, I'll imagine, that a sequence corresponds to a sentence, so a new zero state is initialized after every sentence after the hidden layer are made using every word in that sentence?

Comment: Do you want to classify one sentence (like in sentiment analysis, if a tweet has hate speech or not)?. Then the answer is yes.

Comment: Great. That explains a lot. Guess I had to change slightly to my current implementation.